# Multiple manifest templates per Teams Tookit app

Tags: teams-toolkit

Is it possible to have multiple manifest templates per Teams Tookit app?
I want to have apps with and without offer specified, and with different sets of tabs for a single ASP.NET app.
How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not able to use multiple manifest templates for a single Teams app in current Teams Toolkit, because the manifest template file path is fixed and cannot be configured right now.

For your scenario that the app may have different sets of tabs in your project, you may need to build multiple Teams apps (each has its own manifest template), or **use different code branch** for different app manifest settings.

And there's already a feature request in the toolkit's code repo to track on this requirement: https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/issues/5590.